# Accessibility of "maximum characters reached" in a text field

Tags: html, accessibility, forms, maxlength

I have a text field that can hold a maximum of 15 characters only. I included `aria-label` to say 'First Name (Maximum 15 Characters only)'. I also want to alert users when maximum character is reached and they cannot type further.

What's the best way to do this?

Screen Readers don't seem to support `maxlength`.

Answer (score 3):

It's unfortunate you have to work around this.  Screen readers should honor the `maxlength` attribute and announce the limit for you and periodically tell the user how many characters are left.  But having the max in the label is a good practice for all users.

Screen readers will happily keep giving feedback as you're typing even if you reach the max.  That's pretty bad and I think is a bug in screen reading software.

Since your field is only 15 characters, you probably don't need to give feedback until they reach the end.  If you had 100 characters, then having a "X characters left" label below the field that updates, say, every 20 keystrokes would be helpful.

For now, you can have an [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) region that when your max is hit, you can either inject text into it saying the limit has been reached or you can unhide a child DOM element of that live region. Either way will have the text announced.

```html
<span aria-live="polite" id="myid"> 
  <!-- insert text here from javascript when max reached --> 
</span>
```

or

```html
<span aria-live="polite" id="myid"> 
  <!-- unhide me when max reached -->
  <span style="display:none">You've reached the max</span>
</span>
```